# How do I make this sidebar scrollable?

Tags: css

How do I make this "sidebar" scrollable?  I tried overflow: auto, but that didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/kK2gD/

Comment: Why do I have to click on your fiddle link to see your example markup/code?

Comment: I just thought it'd be easier for you guys to see the html and css seperated out.

Comment: It could have easily been answered without having to see the demo (which is good, that definitely helps and I don't want to discourage providing a demo). And you don't post the full page markup in jsFiddle either: http://jsfiddle.net/kK2gD/2/

Answer (score 3):

Correct the line ending for padding, and reduce the height of the sidebar.

```
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:330px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    background:#eee;
    padding:150px 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wMq2E/

Comment: I don't know that `20px` is "right", maybe `100px` for the `height`, but this is the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/wMq2E/

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it:

```
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:330px;
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
    background:#eee;
    padding:150px 5px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

First, you were missing a `;` in `padding`.

Second, you should set `overflow` to `scroll`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly fine. I found a typo in your css. At the end of

```
padding:150px 5px
```

the `;` is missing. Should work with that.

Comment: @Gregg - If it's the last statement before the end of the definition, the `;` is optional. However, it's easy to forget and add statements later on after the previously "last" statement, causing your problem. So I always put `;` on my statements regardless if I'm handwriting them.

Comment: And this alone does not fix the problem. You also have to adjust the height (I assume to `height: 100px` on the `#sidebar`?).

Answer (score 1):

```
padding:150px 5px;<-- you miss this coma
overflow:auto;
```